# Should I install Electron as a dependency or a devDependency for distribution?

Tags: electron, electron-builder

I built an Electron app and I want to build it, I use Electron-builder. My question is: if I create an installer for Windows with `"win": "NSIS"` without saving electron as a dependency then I send it to a windows computer that doesn't have Electron or even Node.js installed, will the app be installed and running up ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Short answer: Yes, Electron only needs to be a dev-dependency

When `electron-builder` packages an app it packages Electron with it as well regardless if Electron is a dependency or a dev-dependency.

Also the official way of installing Electron is `npm i -D electron@latest`, the `-D` meaning dev-dependency so if the website tells you to install it as a dev-dependency then you're probably good.

<sup>I've tried installing my electron-builder package on computers without Electron or Node.js and it works fine.</sup>

Comment: Thanks for the answer. So -D is the same as --save-dev, yeah ?

Comment: @CugureanuChiril Yes, that's exactly it

Comment: thanks. One more question: In my dist folder generated by electron-builder, I got the .exe, .exe.blockmap, win-unpacked folder and my-app-name.yaml, do I have to share the exe with all these for it to be installed correctly?

Comment: @CugureanuChiril So you only need the `.exe` to install. The `win-unpacked` I usually delete and the `.exe.blockmap` you only need if you're doing auto updates.

Comment: But what is the purpose of .yaml file?

Comment: @CugureanuChiril Not sure

Comment: @CugureanuChiril Does that answer your question? If not, I'm happy to help. If it does don't forget to upvote and accept :)

Comment: what about the other packages ? if we are using a electron-froge to package and get the .exe. Also I am using other packages inside the electron (for instance: keytar) is there a difference between dependencies and dev-dependencies ?

Comment: For more info I am using webpack with electron